# How to disable a specific value in suggestions to be selected in PrimeNG autocomplete?

Tags: angular, primeng, disabled-input, primeng-dropdowns

In `p-autocomplete` list I want to disable keyevents on 2 items in the entire list of suggestions.

I am able to achieve mouse click using (click) and event.stoppropagation().

Comment: What have you tried so far? Should we guess your structure?

Answer (score -1):

I did some research and I got the working solution for this - 
using (keydown) in pautocomplete tag worked.

on keydown event I wrote a method to check for particular values and  cleared the content for selected value.